# SharePoint: Farm backup stuck

Tags: sharepoint-server, backup, farm

Ours is a SharePoint 2010 Server (Single server Farm). We started the Farm backup specifying a local drive folder. After this Backup process screen appeared. However, since then (Last 2) hours there is no update. Refresh of page shows same message. Also there are no errors in ULS or Event Viewer. SharePoint Timer and Administration Services are running.

What could be wrong. What are we missing.

[image]

Comment: how you given the local drive folder it start like \\

Answer (score 1):

Go to backup and Restore > Check backup and restore job status pages, check if there is any record about the process.

Whether there is backup file in the backup location?

You can run the commend below in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and run as administrator to check the backup log:

```
gc -Path \\path\spbr0000\spbackup.log -Wait
```